# Store Hours (group days by hours)

Tags: templating, plugins

I'm using the Store Hours plugin to output store hours like this:

```html
{% set days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'] %}
{% set daysShort = ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'] %}

<dl class="store-details-hours__list">
  {% for dayHours in entry.hoursOfOperation %}
    <dt class="store-details-hours__day">{{ days[loop.index0] }}</dt>

    {% if dayHours.open|length and dayHours.close|length %}

      <dd class="store-details-hours__hours"
        itemprop="openingHours" content="{{ daysShort[loop.index0] }} {{ dayHours.open|date('h:i') }} - {{ dayHours.close|date('h:i') }}">{{ dayHours.open|date('h:i a') }} - {{ dayHours.close|date('h:i a') }}</dd>
    {% else %}
    <dd class="store-details-hours__hours"
      itemprop="openingHours" content="{{ daysShort[loop.index0] }} Closed">Closed</dd>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

</dl>
```

This works okay and outputs like this:

[image]

But what I really need is to be able to group the days if the hours are the same so that it looks like this:

[image]

It's also important that I can set an attribute tag on the `<dd>` of `content="Mo,Tu,We, 10:00-17:00"` So how do I group days of the week and output the hours the way my client wants it to look?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I have a solution to this problem, but it's kind of complicated. There may be a way to simplify this more.

The basic idea is to loop thru your Store Hours field (`entry.hoursOfOperation`) and build a new array (`storeHours`) where the days are combined if the current loop's open and close times match the previous loop's.

```twig
{% set days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'] %}
{% set daysShort = ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'] %}

{# Setup a new array storeHours to hold all you hashes 
   and prev variables to compare things to in the loop 
 #}
{% set storeHours, prevDays, prevDaysShort, prevOpen, prevClose = [],[],[],"","" %}

{# Loop thru your Store Hours field and build the storeHours array #}
{% for item in entry.hoursOfOperation %}

  {# in the first loop, setup the prevOpen and prevClose variables  #}
  {% if loop.first %}
    {% set prevOpen, prevClose = item.open, item.close %}
  {% endif %}

  {# If the prev hours match the current item's hours, 
     add that day's name to the array of prev days, ["Monday","Tuesday"] etc.
   #}
  {% if prevOpen == item.open and prevClose == item.close %}
    {% set prevDays = prevDays|merge([days[loop.index0]]) %}
    {% set prevDaysShort = prevDaysShort|merge([daysShort[loop.index0]]) %}

  {# If it doesn’t match, add prev variables as a hash to the storeHours array,
     Then set all prev variables with current item
   #}
  {% else %}

    {% set storeHours = storeHours|merge([{
      "days" : prevDays,
      "daysShort" : prevDaysShort,
      "open" : prevOpen,
      "close" : prevClose
    }]) %}

    {% set prevDays = [days[loop.index0]] %}
    {% set prevDaysShort = [daysShort[loop.index0]] %}
    {% set prevOpen = item.open %}
    {% set prevClose = item.close %}

  {% endif %}

  {# If last loop, add prev variables as a hash to the storeHours array
     because there won’t be another loop to compare it to.
   #}
  {% if loop.last %}
    {% set storeHours = storeHours|merge([{
      "days" : prevDays,
      "daysShort" : prevDaysShort,
      "open" : prevOpen,
      "close" : prevClose
    }]) %}
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

The `storeHours` data format will be something like this:

```json
[
  {
    "days" : ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"],
    "daysShort" : ["Mo","Tu","We"],
    "open" : "2017-01-21 09:30:00.000000",
    "close" : "2017-01-21 21:00:00.000000"
  },
  {
    "days" : ["Thursday","Friday"],
    "daysShort" : ["Th","Fr"],
    "open" : "2017-01-21 09:00:00.000000",
    "close" : "2017-01-21 17:00:00.000000"
  }
]
```

Once you've created your `storeHours` array, you can use it to output your HTML code.

```html
<dl class="store-details-hours__list">
  {% for item in storeHours %}

    <dt class="store-details-hours__day">
      {{ item.days|first }}{% if item.days|length > 1 %} - {{ item.days|last }}{% endif %}
    </dt>    

    {% if item.open|length and item.close|length %}
      <dd class="store-details-hours__hours" itemprop="openingHours" 
        content="{{ item.daysShort|join(',') }} {{ item.open|date('h:i') }} - {{ item.close|date('h:i') }}">
        {{ item.open|date('h:i a') }} - {{ item.close|date('h:i a') }}
      </dd>
    {% else %}
      <dd class="store-details-hours__hours" itemprop="openingHours" 
        content="{{ item.daysShort|join(',') }} Closed">
        Closed
      </dd>
    {% endif %}

  {% endfor %}
</dl>
```

---

**BONUS ROUND:** if you want to make **Monday the first day of the week**, reorder the `days` and `daysShort` arrays at the top like this:

```twig
{% set days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'] %}
{% set daysShort = ['Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'Su'] %}
```

Then add this line just below it:

```twig
{% set hoursMondayFirst = entry.hoursOfOperation|slice(1,entry.hoursOfOperation|length)|merge(entry.hoursOfOperation|slice(0,1)) %}
```

That makes a new variable using [Twig's slice filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/1.x/filters/slice.html) to take Monday - Saturday (`slice(1|length)`) and merge Sunday at the end (`slice(0,1)`).

Now just use this as the start of your loop:

```twig
{% for item in hoursMondayFirst %}
```

Comment: Will try this a little later. Agree it is a little complex.